# How can I highlight duplicate cells?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'd like a formula that highlights all duplicate cells,  even if they are in different columns.

In [my example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p2pb3Gut0UmHM_Arb7IheEu19CnUhBH_EdbXQRKCCxE/edit#gid=0) `A1` is equal to `D15`, the formula should highlight both, and so on with all worksheet duplicates, regardless of whether or not in the same column.

What would I have to do to accomplish that?

Comment: I found a decent problem description _in the spreadsheet_. I have edited that into the question.

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is to use conditional formatting in each cell, having it trigger with the custom formula `=EXACT({cellA},{cellB})`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a custom formula on conditional formatting such as:

```
=COUNTIF($A:$E,A1)>1
```